# Notifications To Mobile Devices

Tags: php, email, carrier

In PHP if I save the users mobile number into my phpmyadmin database and want to push certain notifications to the users phone I would have to email them at that specified number. How would you go about determining the users carrier to email such as @vtext.com or @at&temail.com or @virginmobile.com ect. How would I determine the ending email to send to? I know there are sites online that can determine this already for you which I can possibly send a curl request to and fetch the carrier it displays on the screen but how do these sites specifically determine these carriers? If they can determine it so can I right? There must be a way?

Answer (score 0):

Most carriers do not offer an email to SMS gateway, so you don't. Use a service designed for sending SMS instead. e.g. Twilio  or Amazon Simple Notification Service.

Comment: https://www.freecarrierlookup.com/ So you're telling me there is no way for this site to actually be finding the correct carrier based on the number you enter? Say I don't want to email their number I just wanna find out the carrier.